# How to mock a response from a package?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to mock a response while using [php-oppwa](https://github.com/bryangruneberg/php-oppwa)

I created this wrapper around that package:

```php
use Bryangruneberg\OPPWA\Factory;
use Bryangruneberg\OPPWA\OPPWAResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class OppwaService
{
    public function client()
    {
        $client = Factory::createClient(
            Config::get('gateways.oopwa_user_id'),
            Config::get('gateways.oopwa_password'),
            Config::get('gateways.oopwa_entity_id'),
            Config::get('gateways.oopwa_url'),
        );

        $api = Factory::createAPI($client);

        return $api;
    }

    public function setupCheckout(int $amount, string $currency, string $paymentType, array $options = [])
    {
        return $this->client()->prepareCheckout($amount, $currency, $paymentType, $options);
    }

    public function checkoutSetupWasSuccessful(OPPWAResponse $response)
    {
        return $this->client()->isPrepareCheckoutSuccess($response);
    }
}
```

And I have this in my controller:

```php
    public function __construct(OppwaService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function show()
    {
        $checkout = $this->service->setupCheckout(23, 'USD', OPPWA::PAYMENT_TYPE_DEBIT);

        if ($this->service->checkoutSetupWasSuccessful($checkout)) {
            $checkoutId = $checkout->getId(); // I am trying to mock this response
        }

        return view('index',['checkoutId' => $checkoutId ?? null);
    }
```

I am trying to mock `getId` in my test,

```php
    /** @test */
    public function checkout_id_exists()
    {
        $this->mock(OPPWAResponse::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('getId')->once()->andReturn('555555555-555555555');
        });

        $this->get(route('checkout.show'))->assertSee('555555555-555555555');
    }
```

But, that doesn't work.. Is it because that `OPPWAResponse` is in the `vendor` directory? 
How can I mock the response?

Comment: You should also mock `OppwaService` and have `setupCheckout` return your mocked `OPPWAResponse`

Comment: mock the wrapper, that's what you've made it for I'd say. (basically the same as @apokryfos suggested, just a bit of layer-shifting)